# Why are slightly different MKA chapter timecodes needed for WAV and OGG?

Tags: linux, audio, vlc-media-player, wav, ogg

I am converting an audio CD to OGG format by ripping it to WAV (using `cdparanoia`) and encoding it as OGG (using `oggenc`).

If I mux the WAV file to MKA with chapter timecodes as reported by `cdparanoia -Q` (the CD track timecodes) then when I play the resulting MKA file in `vlc` each chapter starts exactly in the right place. However, if I mux the OGG file instead of the WAV file the chapters start slightly too late, that is, `vlc` starts each chapter about 0.5-1.5 seconds into the track.

This problem can be resolved by manually adjusting the chapter timecodes after muxing, but I would like to know why this intervention is necessary.

I am using version 4.9.1 "Ich Will" of [`mkvmerge`](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) to mux from WAV/OGG to MKA and I am using version 2.0.3 "Twoflower" of [`vlc`](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to play the files.